# Скриншот с видео или из видео. Как правильно?

Tags: выбор-слов

Скриншот с видео или из видео...

Answer (score 1):

Скриншот делается с монитора, с дисплея или экрана устройства. Из видео или кино получают *стоп-кадр* или просто *кадр*.